# MySQL Count distinct values from one column

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table having three columns:

```
A   B   C
1   2   2
2   2   2
3   1   1
4   1   2
```

I want the count of those values which have C equal to 2 but with distinct values of B

So in this case for C = 2, count = 2 (B=2 and B=1)

I used the following command:

```
Select count(*) from mytable where C=2 group by (B)
```

but it yields:

```
count(*)
3
```

I have tried using "distinct" but it can't be use to select from one column

Comment: `it can't be use to select from one column` - er...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) FROM mytable WHERE C = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sub query like this:

```
Select count(*) from (
    select distinct B where c=2
)
```